# Trouble adding Get-ADuser Properties in my AD powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm having trouble adding the `Get-ADUser` properties to my script. 
Currently the only columns that display in my .csv file are: `Domain`, `Group`, and `Username`.
My goal is to get more info for each user in the groups. 
The output I want to display is: `Domain`, `Group`, `Username`, `Display Name`, `Description`, `Phone number`, & `Email`.

Below is my script:

```
$groups = Get-Content c:\temp\ADGroups.txt
$domains = (Get-ADForest).domains
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $Members = foreach ($domain in $domains) {
        $Groupname = Get-ADGroup -Filter { Name -like $Group } -Server $Domain
        $Groupname |
            Get-ADGroupMember -Server $domain |
            Select @{Name="Domain";Expression={$Domain}},
                @{Name="Group";Expression={$Groupname.Name}}, Name |
            Export-Csv c:\temp\GroupsInfo.CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: No help in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using what you have, change it to this and give it a try...

```
$Groups =  (Get-Content -Path 'c:\temp\ADGroups.txt')
$Domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains

foreach($Group in $Groups)
{
    $Members = foreach ($domain in $domains) 
    {
        Get-ADGroupMember -Server $domain -Identity $Group | 
        Select -Property @{Name="Domain";Expression={$Domain}},
        @{Name="Group";Expression={$Group}},Name
    } 
    $Members
}
```

***Updated for results run***

```
PS C:\Scripts> $Groups =  'Administrators','Guests' #(Get-Content -Path 'c:\temp\ADGroups.txt')
$Domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains

foreach($Group in $Groups)
{
    $Members = foreach ($domain in $domains) 
    {
        Get-ADGroupMember -Server $domain -Identity $Group | 
        Select -Property @{Name="Domain";Expression={$Domain}},
        @{Name="Group";Expression={$Group}},Name
    } 
    $Members
}

# Results 

Domain          Group           Name
------          -----           ----
contoso.com   Administrators  Domain Admins
contoso.com   Administrators  Enterprise Admins
contoso.com   Administrators  Administrator
contoso.com   Guests          Domain Guests
contoso.com   Guests          Guest
```

The same results appear on the export as well..

```
$Members | Export-Csv c:\temp\GroupsInfo.CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
psedit c:\temp\GroupsInfo.CSV

"Domain","Group","Name"
"contoso.com","Administrators","Domain Admins"
"contoso.com","Administrators","Enterprise Admins"
"contoso.com","Administrators","Administrator"
"contoso.com","Guests","Domain Guests"
"contoso.com","Guests","Guest"
```

I also meant to add that you cannot get these properties...

Display Name, Description, Phone number, & Email.

... from what you currently have in your code.

You'd get the from Get-ADUser cmdlet. So, you'll have to add that segment.

***updated as per OP request***

```
$Groups =  'Administrators','Guests' #(Get-Content -Path 'c:\temp\ADGroups.txt')
$Domains = (Get-ADForest).Domains

foreach($Group in $Groups)
{
    $Members = foreach ($domain in $domains) 
    {
        $MemberInfo = Get-ADGroupMember -Server $domain -Identity $Group

        ForEach($Member in ($MemberInfo | where objectClass -eq 'user'))
        {
            Get-ADUser -Identity $Member.SamAccountName -Properties * | 
            Select @{Name="Domain";Expression={$Domain}},
            @{Name="Group";Expression={$Group}},
            SamAccountName,DisplayName,Description,OfficePhone,EmailAddress
        }
    } 
    $Members # | Export-Csv c:\temp\GroupsInfo.CSV -NoTypeInformation -Append
}

# Results


Domain         : contoso.com
Group          : Administrators
SamAccountName : Administrator
DisplayName    : Administrator
Description    : Built-in account for administering the computer/domain
OfficePhone    : 
EmailAddress   : Administrator@contoso.com

Domain         : contoso.com
Group          : Guests
SamAccountName : Guest
DisplayName    : 
Description    : Built-in account for guest access to the computer/domain
OfficePhone    : 
EmailAddress   :
```

***Update as per OP question***

As for this...

> I know its asking for a lot but, is there any way for it to work for
>   nested groups?

For now, as far as I know, this is a limitation of these cmdlets. So, no native way (think parameter or switch) to get nested or indirect groups. You have to handle that on you own code. Again, at least for now.

For example doing something like this in this part of your use case might be an approach...

```
function Get-NestedGroupMember
{
    [cmdletbinding()]

    [Alias('gngm')]

    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Identity
    )

    process
    {
        $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $Identity
        $userdn = $user.DistinguishedName
        $strFilter = "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$userdn)"
        Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter $strFilter -ResultPageSize 1000
    }
}
```

There are always multiple ways to do thing on PS, this is just one.

```
Get-NestedGroupMember -Identity 'SomeUserName' |
Select-Object -Property Name, DistinguishedName
```

You could even leverage this approach to do things a bit differently than what we've covered thus far, since this has access to all the objects associated with the user and you can parse those attributes / parameters / properties as needed.

Comment: Its still only displaying the Domain, Group, and Username columns.  The following error comes up " Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity Get-ADGroupMember -Server $domain -Identity $Group "

Comment: What does that  ADGroups.txt file look like? I ran this in my test lab using the default 'Administrators','Guest' groups and it run fine. Now, in my test lab I only have one domain. See my update showing the output results

Comment: I'm getting the same results, but I want to be able to pull user description for each of the users in each group. The output for each member of the group I want is : Domain, Group, Username, Display Name, Description, Phone number, & Email.

Comment: I guess we were typing at the same time. 8^} --- See my update.

Comment: That's my issue, I'm having trouble adding the Get-ADUser cmdlet to my script. any suggestions on how to include it?

Comment: It's just another forloop, filtering for the user object and doing your select after that one. See my update.

Comment: I know its asking for a lot but, is there any way for it to work for nested groups?

Comment: I don't necessarily want to pull the info from the nested groups I just want the group names to show up because it ignores the nested groups completely. This is the error I'm getting.  

[Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Nested group' under: 'DC=server,DC=server'.
At line:11 char:13
+             Get-ADUser -Identity $Member.SamAccountName -Properties * ...]